# complex grid layout in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Am a newbie to AngularJS. I want to create a gridview layout where each item in the grid is a bit complex layout. For example, an item may have a text, an image and a button. This has to repeat several times over the entire data fetched from the DB & displayed as a grid. A rough sketch of what am saying :

[image]

in the above image, each item in the grid has an image & a text. Imagine each item also having two or three more buttons.

Google+ layout is also similar :

[image]

I can use ng-repeat, but I want a more nice solution (similar to [GridView in the Android world](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)). Also, I want to be able to change a specific item in the grid & reload only that item without reloading the entire grid.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the problem with ng-repeat ? G+ layout is nothing but repeated posts that are positioned depending on screen width.

Comment: @ClémentMalet In ng-repeat, can I have a handle to each row/item that is created? If a row/item is edited, I want to be able to only reload that particular item.

Comment: Also, do I just use the usual html div tags within ng-repeat or is there any component I can use?

Comment: That's a lot of small questions which are already answered on SO. But of course, you can add directives on "ng-repeated" elements, and you can use regular div elements : Angular is here to enhance HTML.

Comment: but how do I keep a handle to each item/row with hg-repeat, @ClémentMalet ?

Comment: That's what angular does.  As long as they point back to the original object (say an array) if you have an editable field who's model (ng-model) is set to that property of the object, when you change the value, it tracks and changes it in most cases.

Comment: ok. thanks! let me try it out